# Waterfall plot in R

Tags: r, machine-learning, ggplot2

I have this test set of an xgboost model: (this is a subset)

```
structure(list(CR = c("nonComplete", "nonComplete", "nonComplete", 
"nonComplete", "nonComplete", "nonComplete", "nonComplete", "nonComplete", 
"nonComplete", "nonComplete", "Complete", "nonComplete", "Complete", 
"Complete", "Complete", "nonComplete", "nonComplete", "nonComplete", 
"nonComplete", "nonComplete"), gender = c(1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 
1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0), CD4.T.cells = c(-0.0349008907108641, 
-0.167823357941815, -0.0726825919321525, -0.141342090175904, 
-0.12913234058027, -0.100366295133698, -0.0140334251429985, -0.131999854867455, 
-0.171941115538424, -0.157944960935716, -0.0634224340918925, 
-0.0153632894466909, -0.0405096553852646, 0.000431687065820086, 
-0.0583557207914038, -0.00268753987845471, -0.0361591359300353, 
-0.0275676103466624, -0.0347852863599745, -0.0233365180732752
), CD8.T.cells = c(-0.157003425700701, -0.162295446209879, -0.210241384645447, 
-0.132089229492629, -0.131185691245605, -0.195870184702658, -0.393927588525216, 
-0.215730281551133, -0.213892169574032, -0.36507259874743, -0.258830995832427, 
0.115914072388193, 0.263855786498894, 0.268931701587371, 0.168447670526868, 
0.203677800360591, 0.201372330210802, 0.151449387551057, 0.193880808261888, 
0.202984324079261)), row.names = c("Pt2", "Pt24", "Pt29", "Pt34", 
"Pt49", "Pt5", "Pt78", "Pt8", "Pt82", "Pt89", "Pt94", "EA595529", 
"EA595597", "EA595647", "EA595654", "EA632171", "EA632234", "EA632813", 
"EA639069", "EA639146"), class = "data.frame")
```

I want to create a waterfall plot to see how does the data separates the values of the target variable (which in this example, called `CR`).

Basically I want something like this more or less:

[image]

I've tried following some guides such as [this](https://www.r-bloggers.com/2015/07/waterfall-plots-what-and-how/) but I don't understand the code. I got lost somewhere. I'll appreciate your help, thanks!

###### EDIT -

The wanted y-axis is the prediction scores of my model, just like in the added picture. The test set is the data I provide above. XGB model:

```
y=2-as.numeric(as.factor(Train_set[,1]))
dtrain <- xgb.DMatrix(data = data.matrix(Train_set[,-1]), label= y)

xgb_params <- list(
  booster = 'gbtree', eta = 0.01,
  max_depth = 7, gamma = 5,
  subsample = 0.75, colsample_bytree = 0.9,
  objective = 'binary:logistic', eval_metric = 'auc')

model <- xgboost(data = dtrain, # the data
                 params = xgb_params,
                 nrounds = 60)
```

Answer (score 2):

You could do

```r
library(ggplot2)

ggplot(df[order(df$CD8.T.cells),], aes(seq(nrow(df)), CD8.T.cells, fill = CR)) +
  geom_col() +
  labs(x = 'Test set') +
  theme(axis.text.x = element_blank(),
        axis.ticks.x = element_blank())
```

[image]

Obviously this looks a little different from your example plot due to the small number of observations in the example data frame.

Comment: Can this be done using a model prediction score? In the example picture I provided, for the y-axis they used score predctions for the test set. How can I apply this? for the y-axis you used only 1 feature, I need to use the predictions.